# how to filter Django objects with a varying number of filter terms

Tags: django

Users can search for articles in my database with a set of terms. For example, "police body camera force".

I then want to return to the user a list of articles where the title or source of the article contains ANY one of the terms the user entered. I'm not sure how to do this, especially since I don't know how many words there will be in the user's query.

I thought the code would be something like this:

```
user_query = "police body camera force"
user_query_term_list = user_query.split(' ')

for term in user_query_term_list:
    results = Article.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains="term")|Q(source__icontains="term"))
```

...and then somehow combine each of the results together in one queryset. If this is the most efficient approach, how do I combine the results from each of the loops into one queryset? And if there is a better way of accomplishing my goal, I would be grateful for the advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querysets are evaluated lazily, so you can just write a normal loop and accumulate:

```
results = Article.objects.none()
for term in user_query_term_list:
    results |= Article.objects.filter(title__icontains=term)
    results |= Article.objects.filter(source__icontains=term)
```